# Может ли подлежащее быть выражено глаголом и существительным одновременно?

Tags: синтаксис, подлежащее

Подлежащее может быть выражено глаголом в инфинитиве. Но может ли подлежащее быть выражено глаголом и именем существительным одновременно? В качестве примера приведу предложение: **Попытка ходить ночью в горы была плохой затеей.**
Какими членами предложения являются слова "попытка" и "ходить"?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 6):

Здесь "попытка" - *подлежащее*, "ходить" - *несогласованное определение* (попытка какая?), по терминологии, приведённой здесь:

https://russkiiyazyk.ru/sintaksis/kakoi-chlen-predlozheniya-infinitiv.html

Answer (score -2):

Это существительный оборот в роли подлежащего. В русском такое не используется, то есть нужно придать предложению русскую структуру — пойти ночью в горы было плохой затеей. Но если вам это не нужно, то можете считать оборот «попытка ходить ночью…» дополнением.

Comment: Вы бы дали какую-то ссылку на правило. Или хотя бы уточнили, что это частная точка зрения.

Comment: @СергейИваненко _... можете считать оборот «попытка ходить ночью…» дополнением._  Дополнением к чему? Где же тогда — по Вашему мнению — подлежащее?